# zero values in multi bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have this barplot and it already a bit messy. But why are the purple and the violette bars overlapping?

```latex
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[title    = Contributions per category
at LaTeX-Community.org,
xbar,
y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
axis x line       = none,
bar width = 5pt,
tickwidth         = 0pt,
enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
%nodes near coords,
symbolic y coords = {other irony, situational irony,
    verbal irony, not-ironic},
]
\addplot coordinates { (0.11,other irony) (0.24,situational irony) (0.21,verbal irony) (0.04,not-ironic) };

\addplot coordinates { (0.06,other irony) (0.21,situational irony) (0,verbal irony)
 (0.45,not-ironic)  };

\addplot coordinates { (0,other irony) (0.17,situational irony) (0,verbal irony) (0.76,not-ironic) };

\addplot coordinates {(0,other irony) (0.17,situational irony) (0,verbal irony) (0.74,not-ironic) };

\addplot coordinates {(0.15,other irony) (0.18,situational irony) (0.37,verbal irony) (0.22,not-ironic) };
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: When one adds `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}` before your code and `\end{document}` after, these issues do not arise. So most likely you set the size of the plot to too small a value. Hard to tell unless you provide a complete example .

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.